# Best Practice for Sorting Distinct Hex Colors in R

Tags: r, color-theory

**Update:** Based on answers, I am researching `ColorBrewer` and `Colorspace` R packages. Due to request, I am re-writing my original question.

**Question:** How to best sort individual, predefined hex colors so that similar colors are grouped together, yet ordered starting with most warm colors, to light colors to coolest colors. I wish to incorporate this in future version of `RanglaPunjab` R package

For example [Cynthia Brewer's spectral colors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YbFwL.jpg) ( reds, blues, greens, etc are together in single stream) illustrates this.

I'm asking for Logic, rather than Code.

[image]

---

So far, I attempted to sort by `Hue`, `Hue + Value`, `Hue * Value`, based on this article, https://www.alanzucconi.com/2015/09/30/colour-sorting/

This question borderlines between R and Color Theory.

Code at the end of this post sorts colors by `Hue`, `Hue + Value`, `Hue * Value` (depends on what you comment or uncomment).

Please tell me (or give hint) on how get similar results as Cynthia Brewer's spectral colors

`Unordered Colors`:

[image]

Ordered based on `Hue`:

[image]

Ordered based on `Hue + Value`:

[image]

Ordered based on `Hue * Value`:

[image]

For Reference, here is original, unordered palette

```
> oldPal
 [1] "#22325f" "#88ce64" "#fbd234" "#b8091f" "#682f4e" "#fdea6e" "#4aec6a" "#fb7894" "#f13111" "#2584a0"
[11] "#6fa42c" "#db3717" "#051a8d" "#ef38a7" "#202c3d"
```

Converted to HSV, then transposed

```
> tHSVcol
               h         s         v
 [1,] 0.62295082 0.6421053 0.3725490
 [2,] 0.27672956 0.5145631 0.8078431
 [3,] 0.13232831 0.7928287 0.9843137
 [4,] 0.97904762 0.9510870 0.7215686
 [5,] 0.90935673 0.5480769 0.4078431
 [6,] 0.14452214 0.5652174 0.9921569
 [7,] 0.36625514 0.6864407 0.9254902
 [8,] 0.96437659 0.5219124 0.9843137
 [9,] 0.02380952 0.9294606 0.9450980
[10,] 0.53794038 0.7687500 0.6274510
[11,] 0.24027778 0.7317073 0.6431373
[12,] 0.02721088 0.8949772 0.8588235
[13,] 0.64093137 0.9645390 0.5529412
[14,] 0.89890710 0.7656904 0.9372549
[15,] 0.59770115 0.4754098 0.2392157
```

**R Code**

```
library(RanglaPunjab)

RenderPal <- function(x,name){

  if ((missing(x)) || (missing(name))){
    stop("Internal error, please troubleshoot")
  }
  n <- length(x)
  old <- graphics::par(mar = c(0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5))
  on.exit(graphics::par(old))

  graphics::image(1:n, 1, as.matrix(1:n), col = x,
                  ylab = "", xaxt = "n", yaxt = "n", bty = "n")
  graphics::rect(0, 0.9, n + 1, 1.1, col = grDevices::rgb(1, 1, 1, 0.8), border = NA)
  graphics::text((n + 1) / 2, 1, labels = name, cex = 2, family = "serif")
}

i <- NULL
oldPal <- NULL
rankorder <- NULL
orderedPal<- NULL
RGBcol <- NULL
HSVcol <- NULL
tHSVcol <- NULL
orderType <- NULL

# Paint the colors
PaintPalette("Teej","Gidha","Jutti3")

# Store the hex values
oldPal <- MergePalette("Teej","Gidha","Jutti3")

# Print hex values
oldPal

# Convert Hex to RGB
RGBcol <- col2rgb(oldPal)

# Print RGB values
RGBcol

# Convert RGB to HSV
HSVcol <- rgb2hsv(RGBcol)

# Print matrix
HSVcol

# Transpose matrix
tHSVcol <- t(HSVcol)

# Print matrix
tHSVcol


# Uncomment following to order by Hue, then Saturation, then Value
rankorder <- order(tHSVcol[,1],tHSVcol[,2],tHSVcol[,3])
orderType <- "Hue Ordering"

# Uncomment following to order by hANDv = Hue + Value
# hANDv <- apply(tHSVcol[,c(1,3)],1,sum)
# rankorder <- order(hANDv)
# orderType <- "Hue + Value Ordering"

# Uncomment following to order by hPRODv = Hue * Value
# hPRODv <- apply(tHSVcol[,c(1,3)],1,prod)
# rankorder <- order(hPRODv)
# orderType <- "Hue * Value Ordering"

rankorder

for (i in 1:length(rankorder)){
  orderedPal[i] <- oldPal[rankorder[i]]
}

# Print old, unordered palette
oldPal

# Print new, ordered palette
orderedPal

RenderPal(oldPal, "Unordered Palette")
RenderPal(orderedPal, orderType)
```

Comment: you might be interested in the [RColorBrewer](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RColorBrewer/index.html) package

Comment: @DanHall Will check this. BTW I modified question to include more colors, if it helps any.

Comment: You can probably do this with some functions from the `colorspace` package. Would you mind just posting the hex codes of the colors in `oldPal`?

Comment: @camille Here are oldPal hex codes
 `"#22325f" "#88ce64" "#fbd234" "#b8091f" "#682f4e" "#fdea6e" "#4aec6a" "#fb7894" "#f13111" "#2584a0" "#6fa42c" "#db3717" "#051a8d" "#ef38a7" "#202c3d"`

Comment: @camille Will check `colorspace`, thanks!

Comment: It's unclear to me what you're asking, especially after checking out the (very interesting) linked article. It gives lots of options and ends with "Sorting colours is a pain. There isn’t a magic function which will order them nicely," yet you ask if sorting by hue is "acceptable." But you don't say what purpose you're doing this for, or what "acceptable" would mean to you. So I can't tell what kind of answer you're looking for, that isn't already given by the linked article.

Comment: @Aaron I clarified my question, top of post

Comment: I'm still not clear on what you're asking. You successfully converted to HSV and sorted by Hue. Did you try sorting by Value? It's commonly associated with "brightness". What about sorting by H+V or H*V to incorporate both? Are there any sorting schemes in the linked article that you link and need help implementing?  Like Aaron, I find lines like "*is sorting based only on hue acceptable*" confusing - acceptable to whom? Seems like you don't find it acceptable, so what are you asking here? Removing that piece and instead focusing on your goal would make this a clearer and better question.

Comment: @Artie: Thanks, but that didn't really help. For example, "How to best...?" Are you disagreeing with the linked article and think there's one best way to do this? If not, see Gregor's question asking about schemes you liked.

Comment: @Gregor I'll re-word my question...

Comment: @Gregor Please see updated post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, you'll have to either use the ordering of one or more RGBA combinations, create your own objects and establish an `order` method, or use a pre-existing package.

[Cynthia Brewer](https://www.geog.psu.edu/directory/cynthia-brewer) has an excellent package, [RColorBrewer](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RColorBrewer/index.html) that uses different color palettes that are ordered, divergent, or unordered. Some of them are optimized for common color blindness conditions.

```
library(RColorBrewer)
display.brewer.all()# to see all of them
```

[image]

`brewer.pal.info` is a data frame with information about each palette

```
head(brewer.pal.info)
#          maxcolors category colorblind
# BrBG        11      div       TRUE
# PiYG        11      div       TRUE
# PRGn        11      div       TRUE
# PuOr        11      div       TRUE
# RdBu        11      div       TRUE
# RdGy        11      div      FALSE
```

Comment: @ArtieLadie I may have misunderstood your question though... on review.

Comment: `Generally, you'll have to either use the ordering of one or more RGBA combinations, create your own objects and establish an order method, or use a pre-existing package.` Interestingly enough I think you answered my question.....